# if-else failing to branch properly, always follows first path

Tags: javascript, angular, if-statement

I've got a selectbox in the site and wanna change another value by this selectox result.

```
 var item = vm.complaintData.item
  if (item == 'test') {
    var another = "done!";
  } else if (item == 'test1') {
    var another = 'not doneé';
  }
```

When I check `item` on console.log, it works fine.
But if-else conditions not working, always getting first condition result.
Whats the problem?

Comment: "Not working" means what? What is this supposed to do? Why are you creating variables like that?

Comment: "Not working" means "always getting first condition result" How should I do that?

Comment: Are you sure `item` is not always the `'test'` value? That's the only way that first branch is executed. As always, set up a breakpoint if you're really baffled.

Comment: I'm sure, item is changing. I see it on console.log

Comment: It's not going down the first branch unless it's set to `'test'` if the code you have here is actually executing. You could try and use `switch` instead, or even `===` out of an abundance of paranoia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a problem with the `var` keyword. Try this:

```
 let item = vm.complaintData.item
 let another = '';
 if (item === 'test') {
    another = "done!";
 } else if (item === 'test1') {
    another = 'not done';
 }
```